# How to override a hard coded WordPress page title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a plugin that will enable users to enter a page title of their choice in a field. However, it doesn't work if the title of the page is hard coded. How can I achieve this?

```
add_theme_support('title-tag');

$the_pyron_options = get_option('the_pyron_option_name');


add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_page_title');


function change_page_title($title) {

    global $post;

    $pageTitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_pyron_title', true);

    if($pageTitle) {
        return $pageTitle;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

I am also not sure how to check if `Title tags` is enabled before call the line below:

```
add_theme_support('title-tag');
```

Comment: You have to call [`wp_get_document_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) in your theme

Comment: Check header.php page.php single.php index.php files in your theme

Comment: @CodeSpirit I do not have access to the theme because this is a plugin.